# Define PageSize when converting from HTML to PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf, aspose, aspose.words

I'm trying to convert html to a pdf-document in aspose words for java. (Version is 17.4.0)

My question is: 
**How can i set the page size and page margins in html?**

In the [documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsjava/Section+Features+Supported+on+HTML+Import) it sounds like i have to set width, height and margin for the section (div-element).

My html looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hello PDF</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page" style="width:210mm; height:297mm; margin-top:0cm; margin-bottom:1cm; margin-left:1cm; margin-right:1cm;">
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My java code:

```
String baseUri = "path/to/doc/";

LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions();
loadOptions.setEncoding(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
Document doc = new Document(baseUri + "test.html", loadOptions);

OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(baseUri + "test.pdf");
doc.save(outputStream, SaveFormat.PDF);
```

My problem is that the resulting pdf has a page size of 215,9 x 279,4mm (instead of 210 x 297mm) and the margin from top is also not 0.

Can anybody tell me how to define this values in my html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that Aspose.Words mimics the same behavior as MS Word does. Your page settings are fine in HTML. If you load the input html in MS Word and convert it to PDF, it will generate document with 215,9 x 279,4mm pagesize as well.

However, you may change page setting of section as per your requirement using Aspose.Words API as following.

I'm Tilal, developer evangelist at Aspose.

```
String baseUri = "path/to/doc/";

LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions();
loadOptions.setEncoding(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
com.aspose.words.Document doc = new com.aspose.words.Document(baseUri +"test.html", loadOptions);

for (Section sectoin : doc.getSections())
{
       PageSetup ps = sectoin.getPageSetup();
       ps.setPaperSize(PaperSize.A4);
       ps.setTopMargin(0.0);
       ps.setBottomMargin(1.0);
       ps.setLeftMargin(1.0);
       ps.setRightMargin(1.0);

}

OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(baseUri +"Test.pdf");
doc.save(outputStream, com.aspose.words.SaveFormat.PDF);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i use you code the document looks correct. My hope was, that i can set all needed layout-features in my html.

Comment: Yes, setting page layout properties in HTML will not impact on HTML to PDF conversion result.